# Set table row id attributes with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I need to make my rows use the id `row_##` when the data is loaded but am having trouble finding out how to pull it off.

The code that I am using for the HTML is:

```html
<tbody data-bind="foreach: deliveryItems">
  <tr data-bind="attr: {id: \'row_\' + id }">
```

Basically I want each table row's id to be `row_##` with the `##` being replaced by the value of '`id`' from the JSON response.

I've made a JS Fiddle with the full example code: https://jsfiddle.net/spyke01/kzcr5Lph/

Comment: Apart from a syntax error with the backslash characters, the code you posted [works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/y2qbueur/1/) as far as I can tell? The jsfiddle has *a lot* of other things going on. Could you try to update the question and extend the code slightly into an [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

your close - this works below.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: deliveryItems">
  <tr data-bind="attr: {id: 'row_' + id }">
```

Comment: This wasn't working for me but this did: <tr data-bind="attr: {id: 'row_' + $data.id }">

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused with trying to escape your strings...

When you create a `data-bind` attribute within a HTML document, the attributes value has to be surrounded by either single or double quotes.

```
<div data-bind=""></div>
```

Now, everything between the quotes will be extracted by knockout and evaluated *as if it was a snippet of javascript*. So you can do all the things you're used to. Now, if you want to input a string, there's one catch: your HTML parser will think you've ended the attribute value quotes if you use the same quote type. E.g.:

```
<div data-bind="text:"hello""></div>
```

Will create a `<div>` with a `data-bind="text:"` attribute-value combination and a `hello` attribute without a value.

You can't escape these quotes because HTML doesn't work with the `\` escape character. For example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="hello \"world\"">
```

Will just give you the placeholder `hello \`. If you want to put the double quotes *around* the attribute as well as *in* the attribute's value, you'll have to use `&quot;`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="hello &quot;world&quot;">
```

Now, luckily, there are two types of quote that **both the [HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) and the JS spec allow**. This means you can use single quotes around your attribute value if you plan to use double quotes inside it, and vice versa.

Which brings us to the easies solution, as already given by the other answerers:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: deliveryItems">
  <tr data-bind="attr: {id: 'row_' + id }">
</tbody>
```

Now, only if you wanted to use a `'` character *inside* your id string, you'd have to use `\'`. E.g.:

```
attr: { id: 'row\'_' + 12 }
```

Would give you:

```
id="row'_12"
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure this out. I had to use this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: deliveryItems">
  <tr data-bind="attr: {id: \'row_\' + $data.id }">
```

Comment: This still won't work. The problem is that you're escaping your quotes outside a string. The escapes would only make sense if you want to use quote characters inside a string. There shouldn't be any difference between `$data.id` and `id` if all `deliveryItems` have an `id` property.

Comment: You're right this does work. I'm not sure why the id was giving me issues previously, it was probably a bug on my side.